# Using Jackson to parse XML with repeated element

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jackson

I am looking for a simple way to parse an XML structure with a repeated element using Jackson. Here is a simplified example:

```
<root>
   <a>
       <x>
           <b>some content</b>
           <c>some content</c>
       </x>
       <x>
           <b>some content</b>
           <c>some content</c>
       </x>    
       ...
       <x>
           <b>some content</b>
           <c>some content</c>
       </x>
   </a>

   ... some other content ...
</root>
```

I would like to collect all the `x` elements in a list or array The problem is that when using something like:

```
XmlMapper().readTree(xml).get("a").fields()
```

the result contains only the last instance of `x` so it looks like some map key gets overwritten. There is a solution using `JsonParser`
e.g.: `XmlMapper().createParser(xml)` but it's a bit icky.

Is there a better way?

**Edit**

The way I read the "Known Limitations" section in the [README](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/blob/master/README.md#known-limitations) , XML seems to be a second class citizen in Jackson. I accept @galuszkak 's answer as it is what it is , but to my mind when a developer invokes `XmlMapper().readTree(xml)` they do not expect XML processing to be shoehorned into JSON processing model with the limitations that come with that approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mentioned here is described in this Github issue:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/187

Basically what is happening is that Jackson is translating XML tree structure in JsonNode data model and this will not work as it's not supported.

There is 2 options described in that Github issue:

- Fully transform this XML to JSON (answer from @cawena on Github)
- Or if you know your data structure to just use answer from p0sitron which is:

Code:

```
List<List<JsonNode>> elA = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, new TypeReference<List<List<JsonNode>>>() { });
assertEquals(3, elA.get(0).size());
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way it is not I who is "trying to do is use XML tree structure in JsonNode data model " - it is Jackson.

Comment: @DavidSoroko I understand how this could sound, apologize if this wasn't well explained/received. Actually you can use Jackson in many ways, the way it was used indicated translating it into JsonNode. I edited my answer to reflect better what is asked.

Comment: works fine in 2.13.2

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I finally figured a solution.

I was using `jackson-dataformat-xml:2.15.2` library.

Here is a piece of XML I tried to parse (a PersonList XML),

```
...
   <DESIGNATION>
      <VALUE>General Manager</VALUE>
      <VALUE>Regional Office</VALUE>
      <VALUE>Interior Monastery</VALUE>
   </DESIGNATION>
...
```

Here is the corresponding data class in Kotlin (for `Designation` & `Value`),

```
//Inside PersonList data class constructor
...
   @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "DESIGNATION")
   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DESIGNATION")
   val designation: List<Value>,
...
...) {  //Inside PersonList data class body
      ...
         @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "VALUE")
         data class Value (
            val value: String?
         )
      ...
     }
...
```

Here is the corresponding Kotlin code for parsing (the PersonList XML),

```
...
   val xmlString = response.body!!.string()
   //Parse XML String
   val xmlMapper: ObjectMapper = XmlMapper.builder()
      .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
      .build()
   val personList = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlString, PersonList::class.java)
...
```

Voilà, it works!!